# In Swift 3, how to convert a dictionary to Object?

Tags: swift, object, dictionary

[I am new to Swift, I don't know is this possible or not, so please suggest me]

I have a dictionary (which is dynamic) like this:

```
let simpleHash = ["testA": "A", "testB": "B", "testC": "C"]
```

I want to convert this to an Object, so that I can access like:

```
simpleHash.testA // instead of simpleHash["testA"]
```

I have tried the below one, but it didn't help

```
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: simpleHash, options: .prettyPrinted)
let decoded = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
```

Can anyone please suggest me on this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What object are you talking about?  And what does your dictionary have to do with JSON?

Comment: @ElTomato I clearly mentioned what I want from the dictionary `simpleHash `

Comment: Look into JSONDecoder.

Comment: You mean a `struct` or a `class` instead of a `Dictionary`?

Answer (score 1):

Swift will need an explicitly declared variable for testA so you will not be able to be 100% dynamic. But, since you need to use the variable in code, it will be known at some point. Given this and in the spirit of minimizing the declaration constraints, you could define a class that uses the dictionary as its internal storage and exposes the key values as computed properties.

here's an example:

```
class DictionaryBased
{
   var content:[String:Any]
   init(_ dictionary:[String:Any])
   { content = dictionary }

   func get<T>(_ key:String, _ defaultValue:T) -> T 
   { return content[key] as? T ?? defaultValue }

   func set<T>(_ key:String, _ value:T)  
   { content[key] = value }
}

class SimpleHash:DictionaryBased 
{}
```

With this, you can add computed properties as needed (and where needed) using extensions.

```
extension SimpleHash
{
  var testA:String { get { return get("testA", "") }  set { set("testA",newValue) } }
  var testB:String { get { return get("testB", "") }  set { set("testB",newValue) } }

  // if variables are "read-only", you don't need the set { } part
  var testC:String { get { return get("testC", "") }  }
}
```

You can add variables that are typed or not and support optionals or, (as above) provide default values.

```
extension SimpleHash
{
  var testD:Any?    { get { return get("testD", nil) }  set { set("testD",newValue) } }
  var testE:String? { get { return get("testE", nil) }  set { set("testE",newValue) } }
  var testF:Date?   { get { return get("testF", nil) }  set { set("testE",newValue) } }
}
```

To use this "dictionary based" object, you would need to create an instance at some point and give it the dictionary's content:

```
let simpleHash = SimpleHash(["testA": "A", "testB": "B", "testC": "C"])

simpleHash.testA  // "A"
simpleHash.testD  // nil
```

Note that, this isn't going to be as efficient as using native properties and mapping the dictionary to each physical variable.  On the other hand, it is a lot less code so. If the variables are not referenced often, the extra overhead may be an acceptable trade off for simplicity and flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `struct` to hold your `Dictionary` values:

```
struct SimpleStruct {
  // properties are Optional since they might not be matched
  let testA: String?
  let testB: String?

  // this one has a default value
  let testC: String

  // init that takes a Dictionary
  init(dictionary: [String:Any]) {
    // set the Optional ones
    self.testA = dictionary["testA"] as? String
    self.testB = dictionary["testB"] as? String

    // set the one with a default
    self.testC = dictionary["testC"] as? String ?? "C"
  }
}

let foo = SimpleStruct(dictionary: ["testA": "A", "testB": "B", "testC": "C"])

// force-unwrapping for brevity
// you should actually test before using
print(foo.testA!) // prints A
print(foo.testB!) // prints B
print(foo.testC)  // prints C
```

Comment: Better to make the initializer failable, than to make all the properties optional

Comment: @Alexander True, a failable initializer would also work. I didn't make this one failable because I included a default value for one of them.