# How to get an array with objects to a model in Xcode from Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array of objects like this stored in firestore:
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5ZlV.png)

I have a model for the whole exercise:

```
import Foundation
import Firestore

protocol  DocumentSerializable {
    init?(dictionary:[String:Any])
}


struct Exercise {
    var title: String
    var language: String
    var translated: String
    var uid: String
    var userId: String
    var dueDate: Int
    var lastOpen: Int
    var words: Array<Any>

    var dictionary:[String:Any] {
        return [
            "title":title,
            "language":language,
            "translated":translated,
            "uid":uid,
            "userId":userId,
            "dueDate":dueDate,
            "lastOpen":lastOpen,
            "words":words
        ]
    }
}

extension Exercise : DocumentSerializable {
    init?(dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        guard let title = dictionary["title"] as? String,
            let language = dictionary["language"] as? String,
            let translated = dictionary["translated"] as? String,
            let uid = dictionary["uid"] as? String,
            let userId = dictionary["userId"] as? String,
            let dueDate = dictionary["dueDate"] as? Int,
            let lastOpen = dictionary["lastOpen"] as? Int,
            let words = dictionary["words"] as? Array<Any>

            else {return nil}

        self.init(title: title, language: language, translated: translated, uid: uid, userId: userId, dueDate: dueDate, lastOpen: lastOpen, words: words)
    }
}
```

I then want to get the words to a model like this:

```
import Foundation
import Firestore

protocol  DocumentSerializable2 {
    init?(dictionary:[String:Any])
}

struct Word {
    var translation: String
    var word: String



    var dictionary:[String:Any] {
        return [
            "translation":translation,
            "word":word

        ]
    }
}

extension Word : DocumentSerializable2 {
    init?(dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        guard let translation = dictionary["translation"] as? String,
            let word = dictionary["word"] as? String
            else {return nil}

        self.init(translation: translation, word: word)
    }


}
```

I can then retrieve the data with this function:

```
func loadData() {
        docRef = db.collection("exercises").document(exerciseId)

        docRef.getDocument{ (docSnapshot, error) in
            guard let docSnapshot = docSnapshot, docSnapshot.exists else { return }
            let data = docSnapshot.data()
            self.exerciseArray = docSnapshot.data().flatMap({_ in Exercise(dictionary: data)})
            let exercise = self.exerciseArray[0]

            print(exercise.words)

            self.language1Label.text = exercise.language
            self.translateLabel.text = exercise.translated
            self.navigationItem.title = exercise.title
        }
    }
```

I can get the words to an array of objects and when printed the array looks like this:
[printed array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TYv6.png)

How do I now get the words to my word model?
My own guess is that I should change how I save the words array in the exercise model but I can not wrap my head around how I would do that.

Thanks!

Comment: tried **Array<Word>** ???

Comment: @Alexander Singh where you  are retrieving the transalation and word fields and  we need to create spereate swift file for these model class and where we call these model class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
struct Word {
    var translation: String
    var word: String

    var dictionary:[String:Any] {
        return [
            "translation":translation,
            "word":word
        ]
    }

   // init that takes a Dictionary
   init(dictionary: [String:Any]) {
       self.translation = dictionary["translation"] as? String ?? "No Value"
       self.word = dictionary["word"] as? String ?? "No Value"
    }
}
```

Then you can set the value like:

```
let words = [Word]()
for record in exercise.words {
    words.append( Word(dictionary: record))
}
```

Found the structure for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46334806/9333764) and appropriated it for this question.

Comment: where we need to write and where we are getting the firestore data.